# Flow Chart Generator Software File Extension

Tags: java, swing, flowchart

I am making a flowchart generator software. Now, I want to add a feature so that user can save the flowchart in edittable file format other than jpg or pdf.

Which file format should I use so that user will be able to edit the flowchart at any time ???

Also, can I create a file extension of my own for that purpose ??

Is it possible using JGraphx Library ?? If yes, How ??

Answer (score 0):

> Which file format should I use so that user will be able to edit the flowchart at any time?

That would be up to you, but if you want a file format that can be read with a text editor, XML would be a good choice.

> Also, can I create a file extension of my own for that purpose?

Yes, you can.  See this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920501/how-to-save-a-file-to-a-chosen-directory-with-jfilechooser/13996949#13996949) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

If you would prefer a format that can be viewed as an image, I recommend [Scalable Vector Graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics).  SVG format is essentially XML, with certain tags and attributes defined to produce shapes, paths, text, and more.  You can also include your own metadata for reading the file back into your program for further editing; SVG images can also be edited with [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) and other graphics programs, or (for sufficiently advanced users) with a text editor.

The canonical file extensions are `.svg` for plain-text documents, or `.svgz` for SVG documents compressed with the gzip algorithm.

JGraphX seems to have [some support for SVG](http://jgraph.github.com/mxgraph/java/docs/com/mxgraph/util/mxCellRenderer.html#createSvgDocument%28com.mxgraph.view.mxGraph,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20double,%20java.awt.Color,%20com.mxgraph.util.mxRectangle%29), but you might have to edit the result and/or code your own in order to save the graph connection information.