# Saving Object to a file

Tags: java, save, jfilechooser, fileoutputstream

I am making a music program where the user can create it own songs. When you have created a song in the program I would like the user to be able to save it. So what you are saving is an object that I get from mainframe.getSound. I'm not really sure how I would get the file to be saved at the location on the hard drive where the user chooses from showSaveDialog (the popup window).

Also I would like to name the file that will be saved in the showSaveDialog box. Not sure how I would do that. I know how I give the file a name in the code but that's not what I want.

Any help would be mostly appreciated.

Here's my current code:

```
private void save(){
    try{

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showSaveDialog(this.getParent());
        File file = new File();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(mainframe.getSound());
        oos.close();

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems alright to me, what errors are you getting? Could you restate your question to be more specific?

Comment: I don't get any errors. It's just that the file does not get saved on the location I choose in the showSaveDialog window.

Nor does it get the name I put in the showSaveDialog.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920501/how-to-save-a-file-to-a-chosen-directory-with-jfilechooser

Comment: @user3499562 Are you trying to allow the user to name the file? Like when the Save Dialog window comes up, you want the user to be able to name the file. Does the JFileChooser not allow a user to name the file?

Comment: I think it does. I get the option to write in the filename in Save Dialog Window. But what i write does not get attached to the actual file.

Comment: My bad. I forgot to mention. in File file = new File(); Java want a string for a name to the File. Here is where I would want to get the name from Show Dialog Window.

Comment: @user3499562 Oh because I had that same problem last semester, and I couldn't find a way for JFileChooser to do it, so I just ended up pulling the String from the textbox in the Save Dialog, and then create a new file with the String in the location the user chose.

Comment: @user3499562 I was in the middle of typing an answer lol. Did you have to make a method to return the JTextField from the JFileChooser? Or was there already some built in method to get the String?

Comment: Haha lol. I got the string by doing: String fileName = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName(); and then put it in -> FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName); But the problem I have not is that I don't get the right path for the filed to get saved on.

Comment: I don't know where to implement the path from String path = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath(); so the file get saved on the right place.